# javascript onclick page jumps to top

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

On click on the img it opens an overlay.
T
he overlay opens but the html jumps back to top.
I tried it with:

```
javascript:void(0);
javascript: return null;
```

neither works?

here the short version of my code

```
<img onclick="popUp(event,this)" src="images/test/1.jpg"  >

function popUp(e, element) {

    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";

    return null;
}


#popupWrapper
    background-color: rgba(blue, 0.4)
    display: none
    height: 100%
    left: 0
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    width: 100%
```

Comment: Is image wrapped with a link?

Comment: nope. Not yet ;) i will try this

Comment: No, you don't need a link :)

Comment: actually i didnt hel :(

Comment: are you using a '#' as the href for your link?

Comment: Can you show more html code? Is there something around the image?

Comment: Do you have any other elements on the html that you bind events to? You might be a victim of the bubbeling effect

Comment: there are no events. And there's only a wrapper around it. But as i said there could be a problem with the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere else in your code, there's an event doing something you aren't aware of. Nothing within the mentioned code should be causing this effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
function popUp(e, element) {

    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";

    return false;
}
```

or you could also use

```
function popUp(e, element) {

    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: return false not going to do anything without `onclick="return popUp(event,this)"`